# A bank employee visited my flat in Germany

Tags: germany, banking, rental

My landlord told me that someone working for the bank will come visit the flat and because I was busy I did not ask why. Then this bank employee came and took a picture of the flat ( and my furniture) and when I asked him about the reason he told me it is for the bank. I thought maybe this is common here in Germany. But I still don't understand why a bank employee visit the flat I am renting a take pictures of every room?

Comment: The owner may have applied for a loan with the property as security. In which case the bank will want to ensure that the property exists, is in mortgageable condition etc.

Comment: Yes that may be the only explanation. But does that require taking picture of every room?

Comment: Possibly. Did you see the person’s ID?

Comment: No. But he had a tablet and was filling out a form.

Comment: This question as it is now is opinion-based. We cannot know why a bank employee has made photos.

Comment: I'm a notary public in the US. US notaries are often asked to do financial work for banks that do not have a local office where the service is located. I have been asked to take pictures of businesses, and fill out forms, when the business was applying to a bank to be allowed to accept credit cards.

Comment: Ask the landlord. We can't know.